# Create js Objects from Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-js-interop

I have js code that needs to be translatable to Dart:

```
(function() {
    var s, e;
    s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = “//someurl.com/somefile.js";
    s.async = true;
    e = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    e.insertBefore(s, e.firstChild);
    this.OBJECT = this.OBJECT || {};
    this.OBJECT.array = this.OBJECT.somearray || [];
})();

OBJECT.somearray.push({
    val1 : “foo",
    val2 : “bar"
});
```

Basic part to embed script into head I did like this:

```
ScriptElement scr = new ScriptElement()
  ..src = "//someurl.com/somefile.js";
  ..async = true;
querySelector('head').append(scr);
```

But I don't know how to correctly check if OBJECT and OBJECT.somearray exists in somefile.js and push an object item in it.

Comment: Do you think that I didn't tried to look for it in google on dart documentation before post it here? I will be much helpful if you could help to me with some example code.

Comment: But... the documentation has example code :-/ [Here as well](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html). To create an object, call `new JsObject(context['Object'])`, to create an array, `new JsObject(context['Array'])`. There is also `JsArray` which might be helpful. I mean, I don't know where exactly you are stuck. If you post what you have tried and which error you get, we might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

With [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html) you can check the presence of a global variable with :

```dart
bool exist = context.hasProperty('OBJECT');
if (exist) {
  final o = context['OBJECT'];
  if (!o.hasProperty('somearray')) {
    o['somearray'] = new JsArray();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing some things up, especially the scope of the function of your JS. I don't want to make assumptions about your js, but it looks as if you do not properly initialize your OBJECT. You want to add something like this to your javascript

```
function myObject(){
  this.array = []
}
```

In dart you can, as Felix pointed out in the comments then create this function. There are different options. One is to access JS functions via dart:js (see felix comment), another is to use the js-interop library. I am not particularly sure what the differences are but i find the js-interop library to have a *much* cleaner API (https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop)

```
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
var yourObject = js.Proxy(js.context.myObject);
yourObject.array.push("...");
```

js.interop makes javascript calls available on an object, rather than using callMethod etc. but I guess it relies on dart2js rather than dart only.

Comment: The cleaner API comes with a cost in size and speed (because _package:js_ uses _dart:mirrors_ and _noSuchMethod_).